# Select * from Employee where employeDepartment in ('CSE') in Flink gives parse exception

Tags: sql, apache-flink

I have tried Flink with sql query when I use IN query in Flink SQL it gives error.

I have used single quotes then it gives below error because internally single quote treated as char.

```
Class Employee 
private String employeId;
private String employeDepartment;


StreamTableEnvironment streamTable = ..;

Table table = streamTable.sqlQuery(
                            "select * from employee where employeDepartment In ( 'CSE')")
```

> Caused by: org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: Values passed to IN operator must have compatible types
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInstWithCause.ex(Resources.java:505)
> at org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInst.ex(Resources.java:599)

I have tried with `` backtick then it gives column not found . How can I use IN query in Flink SQL. I have passed values like select * from employee where employedepartment IN (`CSE`)

then it gives CSE column not found in any table.

Comment: can you show some code and tables involved

Comment: its is simple in Query clause execute by Apache Flink you can take any example, its is not related to data

Comment: it seems more like a bug, you should report it to the team, looking at the function that are implemented, it is still to soon for production.

Comment: What type is the employeDepartment column? Please share the table definition.

Comment: The Type for (employeDepartment) Array of String. but you can try with any other data type as well.

Comment: What version of Flink is this?

Comment: 1.17.0 flink version and we have connect for mongodb connector Flink

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, the syntax for a literal array of strings is like this:

```sql
'{"Alice", "Bob", "Charles", "Daisy"}'
```

If the employeDepartment field in the employee table is an array of strings, since you must use the same type in the IN clause, it'll be like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employeDepartment IN ('{"CSE"}');
```

However, it does seem odd that the employeDepartment would be an array. Perhaps it should be a String?

Comment: In Mongodb we can find using -> {employeDepartment: {$in: ["CSE"]}} In Mongodb the employeDepartment : [0: "CSE", 1: "ME"] like this so we can query above like in mongodb compass. but in sql data base as per my understanding the array of string is stored like employeDepartment: ["CSE", "ME"] so we can query IN ('CSE') in sql syntax. let me know if I am wrong

Comment: according to flink at the time of registering the table I have defined the employeDepartment ARRAY<STRING> <code>streamTable
                            .executeSql(
                                    "create table if not exists employee (employeeId STRING, employeDeparment ARRAY<STRING>) WITH ('connector' = 'mongodb', 'uri' = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017', 'database' = '', 'collection' = 'employee')</code>

Comment: I have taken employee table as an example for asking in query issues. but our goal is to ask in query clause issues run by Apache Flink

Comment: In Apache Flink 1.17.0 version if we using IN ('{"CSE"}') stil the same issues.

Comment: Not sure what's going on. But I don't believe [0: "CSE", 1: "ME"] is an array. That looks like a mongodb document.

Comment: Ya that is mongodb document store for Array<STRING>, mongodb store Array of String like this. but we donot here to discuss how mongodb store array of string. we need to fix In query clause for Apache Flink. if anyone able to do , could you please share your thought for In clause

Comment: this document says -> https://calcite.apache.org/docs/history.html#v1-34-0 IN clause break changes has been fixed in 1.34.0 version and release date is 13 march 2023 and Apache Flink 1.17.0 version release 9 march 2023. is it possible this changes not inlcuded in Apache Flink Table API

Comment: Flink 1.17 uses calcite 1.29.0. Right now the Flink master branch is using calcite 1.30.0.